# FlowMap Visualization on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I am looking for a javascript library to visualize the flow distribution from one place to other places.

Ideally, this flow should be represented as arrows from that single source to multiple destinations and different arrows are weighted by their thickness / color.

It should look similar to that one (but this is done using Java library not JavaScript)
[image]

I know that I can do it manually by drawing multiple routes with different colors/ stroke widths.. but I wonder if there exist a library that done do the same job faster and probably in a more appealing way..

Thanks,
Moustafa

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a javascript library for doing this: https://github.com/teralytics/flowmap.gl

With this library you can make an interactive flow map like below:

[image]